# Firestore subcollection vs array

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

First of, I know how Firestore works and have spent a lot of time, evaluating different approaches for a good structure. Still I am considering following scenario:

There is a database of recipes. Users can add recipes. Every user can choose from the user-generated list of recipes to state which ones they know how to cook.

Now I want users to share their list of recipes with others. This is where I am not sure how this can be best accomplished using Firestore. The trick is, that I want to show all the recipes at once, and don't want to paginate them.

I am currently evaluating two possibilities:

### Subcollections

Whenever a user shares his list, the user looking at said list will have to load the entire list of the recipes which can result in a high amount of document reads (I suppose realistically ~50, in very rare cases maybe 1000).

Pros:

- More natural structure
- Easier to maintain (e.g. deleting a recipe, checking if a specific one exists)
- Easier to add fields (e.g. timeOfCreation, comment, personalRating, ...)

Cons:

- Can result in a high amount of reads on the long run

### Arrays

I could save every known recipe (the id and an imageURL) inside the user's document (or as a single subdocument "KnownRecipes") within an array. This array could be in form of

```
recipesKnown: [{rid: 293ndwa, imageURL: image1.com, timeAdded: 8371201332}, 
               {rid: 9012831, imageURL: image1.com, timeAdded: 8371201871},
               {rid: jd812da, imageURL: image1.com, timeAdded: 8371201118},
               ...
              ]
```

Pros:

- I only need one document read whenever someone wants to see another user's list
- Reading a user's list is probably faster

Cons:

- It's hard to update a specific recipe (e.g. someone wants to change the imageURL: I need to change the list locally and send the entire document as an update to the server - since I cannot just change a single element in the array)
- When a user decides to have around 1000 recipes (this will maybe never happen, but it could), the 1MiB limit of the Firestore limit could be reached. A possible workaround would be to create a seperate document and split those two arrays into these two documents.

---

For me, the idea with Subcollections seems to be the more "clean" solution to this problem, but maybe I am missing some arguments on why one of those solutions would be superior over the other.

My most common queries are as follows (ordered descending by importance):

- Which recipes can a user cook
- Add a recipe a user can cook to the user's list
- Who can cook a specific recipe (there is a Recipe -> Cooks subcollection)
- Update an existing recipe a user can cook

Comment: It sounds to me like you have a good understanding of the difference between the two.

Comment: If you are asking for differences between Firestore subcollection and arrays, I can also say that the answer stays in your question. Do you also have any other question related to that?

Comment: Well, as mentioned, I am hoping to be missing some important pros/cons that can help me make a decision easier. Also not sure how good it is to go for bad design here (by using Arrays), to reduce the number of reads by factor 100. I know the difference pretty well (except that I don't know the exact capabilities of using arrays). Would following be a legit structure considering it being top-level in a dedicated subdocument: `[dynamicId]: {imageURL: "example.com", name: "SomeName"}, [dynamicID]: {...},...`? So I would just replace the concept of my array approach with a map.

Comment: @thomas Did you end up getting an answer to this from other sources or maybe by evaluating it yourself? I'm just curios to hear as I'm wondering about a similar issue. Cheers

Comment: @riper No, sorry. I decided to use an Array in my case, but am not 100% happy about that.

Comment: Just curious if there's any updates or post-evaluations so far haha

Comment: @Max Not really, I basically decided to always use a single document (as seen in Arrays) whenever I need to load more than one of them at the same time. I have not reached the file limit in any of my cases yet and hope this stays like that :)

Comment: @Thomas I'm doing something similar but I will have the recipes in the own collection and have userId as property for searching them. You can also have date and other properties on it that you can use in the future to select/filter/sort data. If its the amount of data coming back, you can also use the 'select' on your queries.

Comment: I'm considering this right now, but isn't there a third option, where you use a subcollection, but with the limited data you have shown in the array above?..

Comment: @Thomas do you iterate over the recipes? I'm trying to do something similar and when I try to iterate over my songs, I get duplicate IDs and see only one song. I posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71425159/swift-firebase-array-of-map-why-are-the-documentids-for-each-album-duplicate

Answer (score 8):

The answer to your question depends on the level of scalability you want to achieve.

If by design the amount of sub-data you want to store is limited and very low, you should use arrays, since you reduce the number of document reads, which means lower costs.

If your sub-data is supposed to increase "unlimitedly" over time, you should use sub-collections.

If you're building a database which is not supposed to scale in any direction (Proof of concept, very small business, etc.) just go with what you feel more comfortable with.

Answer (score 3):

I'm researching the same question...

One of the questions is whether the data held in the document will be ever go pass 1MB that is the limit for a document. Researching a bit on how much it can be held in plain text in 1MB well it's a hell of a lot. Still if it were to be incredible bigger it would crash in the end. Thus if you think in a big-big way sub-collections.

If we had to use the Firebase element logic the answer would be sub-collections.

Still I guess the major point is the data pulled. If you call the user you will directly be pulling out that MB of data. Instead with a sub-collection it won't load, even if you loaded it you can still lazy-load.

I guess for the kind of setup you are doing sub-collections.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I actually chose arrays in my case, since I always want to load all recipes at the same time, whenever a profile is loaded.

Comment: Great! I use both in the end. I need it that way, lol. Thanks for replying back, I wanted to know your choice.

Answer (score 1):

`key` is an additional `collection`'s con/pro

`key` could help to avoid duplicates; but this requires thinking of what is duplicate's definition (which might change);

`array`'s no-key behavior could be emulated via auto-id.

p.s. @Thomas's list of pros/cons in the question has been quite helpful.