# What's an elegant way to upload nested arrays with objects and other fields to Firestore? (Node.js, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have data that I would like to deploy to a Firestore collection from a cloud function that runs on Node10.

The collection is called "activities" and should hold united arrays with objects and additional fields.

First of all, this is the most important array with objects:

```
listOfNonEmptyObjects = [ 
 { pronounsDefinite: 'I' },
 { verbsInfinitiv: 'work' },
 { prepositions: 'in' },
 { articles: 'the' },
 { nouns: 'garden' } 
];
```

This is how I upload it, while the sessionID_original is basically the document name and the intentDisplayName is just a string to create the object inside arrayUnion:

```
return writeToDatabase (
 sessionID_original,
 {"activities" : admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(createObject(intentDisplayName, listOfNonEmptyObjects))}
);
```

These are the functions for this:

```
function createObject(key, list){
    var test = {};
    test[key] = list;
    return test;
}

function writeToDatabase(sessionID_original, data) {
    const docRef = db.collection('users').doc(sessionID_original);
    
    return db.runTransaction(t => {
      return t.get(docRef)
      .then(doc => {
        t.set(docRef, data, {merge: true});
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(`Error writing to Firestore: ${err}`);
    });
}
```

Now this is what it looks like when I look in Firestore:

[Screenshot of collection with listOfNonEmptyObjects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Gw6.png)

But now I would like my functions to add a timestamp or additional information to the data:

[Screenshot of collection with listOfNonEmptyObjects and timestamps and booleans and so on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyOpn.png)

When I try this it gives me an error that I can't write nested arrays.
But then how can I achieve this data structure. Or is my data structure a bad one?

Another attempt could be to just put a timestamp in the listOfNonEmptyObjects.
But I think this would make it more difficult to read the timestamps then.

So every time there is a new activity or something I would like the functions to add it to the activities collection with a timestamp and maybe other fields like booleans etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me that you are thinking about Firestore in the correct way.

Firestore is a Document Store Database.  For the most part, you will read and write entire Documents (JSON objects or sets of key/value pairs) at at time.  Though you can make nested and complicated data structures within a single document, there are limitations in terms of overall size and index capabilities that will ultimately restrict the usefulness of a single document being complex (see [Firestore limits and quotas](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits))

It sounds to me like the elements you are putting in your array might rather benefit from being their own documents?

There have been a few good threads on the subject of "Firestore arrays vs subcollections".  [This one seems to call out the pros/cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55926950/firestore-subcollection-vs-array) quite well.

Comment: Thank you, I think that was my problem. The linked article made it clear to me.

Comment: Excellent!  Can you please mark one of the answers as accepted so that the thread is now considered complete?