# How can i add new indexes to an array in an existing document in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Good morning, I am working on building out a portion of an app where a user can add team members. Working with the set function created the array I wanted in firestore, but I'm unable to add new indexes to that array with more teams. The user should be able to add as many as they like. After doing some searching I thought the arrayUnion option in the update function would help my needs, but when I add more data from the form, the data in index [0] just gets overwritten rather than populating index ['1']. Below are some images that will illustrate my problem.
[image]
Here is the code that returns the results so far
[image]

The document id is the users uid and I'd like to keep it that way to query all teams associated with that user, How can I add new indexes to an existing array with the same documentid of the current user? If an array isnt feasible here, I also tried to get the result I wanted with an object and that wasn't updating the way I needed it to either.

Comment: why not make `team` a collection and add teams into it with the `.add()` method ? [.add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document)

Comment: Sorry, my screenshot doesnt show it, but Team is actually a collection where the document you see is the current users uid. Are you suggesting just have firebase auto generate the ids and store the uid on the document that gets created? Also if done that way, how will multiple teams associated with one user get tracked? would that also be by the user_id field?

Comment: just to clarify some stuff. in the "main" collection `Teams` there will be a document for each user (`doc(uuid)`). and each user is supposed to have ONE single `team` that needs to store data from multiple users

Comment: The way it's setup now, the main collection is Team, yes. my initial thinking was to have a document for each user that is their uid, yes. each user can have multiple teams and I initially set that up as an array within the document to store those teams. Is my thinking sound with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so, I would suggest to change the approach to have a collection inside each user document instead of an array. Some benefits would be that you're not limited to the 1mb limit that a document can have, but also that queries are more robust for collections.

To add a new team member you would use the `.add()` method, and for querying you have a lot more built in options. [query documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

Here is another so topic on the differences between [using a subcollection or an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55926950/firestore-subcollection-vs-array)

**EDIT**

for your original question, the problem is that in Firestore, your array is an array of maps (objects), but you're calling arrayUnion with the individual fields. consider something like this:

```
db.collection("Teams").doc(uuid).update({
    team: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
              this.team  // object { selected: true, firstName: "abc", ... }
          )
})
```

Comment: Are you suggesting making a Teams sub collection in my Users collection and using the .add() method that way? In that case, wont the cost of reads greatly increase  as more users get created that add multiple teams? I'd just like a little clarity on that part

Comment: yes it would increase the query cost, to get all the users in a particular team you would use <number of members> reads. what option is better depends on your use case, but this is another topic, [data modeling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lW7DWV2jST0). I've also updated my answer to provide a solution to your original problem

Comment: In the solution you added to your question, would that add new indexes to the array or just overwrite the data in index[0]?

Comment: as per the docs arrayUnion appends the provided object to the array, on the condition that it's unique. it won't override the 0-th index

Comment: I tried the suggested idea in your answer, and got an error: Function FieldValue.arrayUnion() called with invalid data. Nested arrays are not supported

Comment: I've seen that mentioned in the docs, but my issue is that it's been overwriting the old data entered even when new information is put in the form. I think it may be because the same fields are still getting filled out.

Comment: Nevermind, I got the solution to work by adding a spread operator in the arrayUnion function. For those who see this later, all i did to get it to work was: 

db.collection("Teams").doc(uuid).update({
    team: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
              ...this.team  
          )
})

Now i get the desired behavior which is new indexes being created when new data is entered.