# Writing to Firebase Firestore React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

so I have a problem right now. I'm entering the users dates into cloud firestore like this:

[image]

so this is a user collection, with a document by user's id's and then the dates are entered as a list. But whenever I refresh the page and enter new data, all the previous data disappears.

So I'm wondering how do I enter data so that it goes like collection(userCalendar).doc(USERID).collection(dates) and then it has all the user's data entered as strings rather than an array like I've been doing.

My code for the way it's behaving right now is below. Thank you! :)

```
export const allEvents = [];

const Calendar = () => {
const [date, setData] = useState([]);



const handleDateClick = async (DateClickArg) => {


      if (DateClickArg.jsEvent.altKey) {
        const title = prompt("Enter title", DateClickArg.dateStr); // allows user to put a title in
        // making object
        const event = {
          title: title ? title : DateClickArg.dateStr,
          start: DateClickArg.date,
          allDay: true
        }

        allEvents.push(event)

        const db = fire.firestore();
        let currentUserUID = fire.auth().currentUser.uid
        const doc = await fire
          .firestore()
          .collection("userCalendar")
          .doc(currentUserUID)
          .get()

        db.collection("userCalendar")
          .doc(currentUserUID)
          .set({
            activites: allEvents
          })

      }
}
```

Comment: You are currently overwriting existing array. Also where is `allEvents` declared and are existing events included in that array?

Comment: Hi, I think my logic is off when i push event to allevents, i keep thinking it'll work and keep adding the events, but i think using an array is a bad approach, is it possible to just keep adding the event object to the document without the use of an array? @Dharmaraj

Comment: how would I stop overwritting the array and just keep adding to it? or to just have another collection inside the document with all the dates, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `arrayUnion()` to add new items to an array however it'll be difficult for you to query activities of a user.

For example, you cannot fetch a single activity from that array but you'll have to fetch all of them get the required one. Additionally, you cannot update an object in an array directly in Firestore.

Also a document has a max size limit of `1 MB` so if a user can have many activities, it'll be best to create sub-collection.

I would recommend restructuring the following way:

```
users -> { userId } -> activities-> { activityId }
(col)      (doc)         (col)          (doc)
```

All of user's activities/events are now in a sub-collection "activities" and each activity would be a document instead of an array item. With this you can easily read/update/delete a single activity.

Also checkout: [Firestore subcollection vs array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55926950/firestore-subcollection-vs-array)

Comment: how would i go about given each activity an ID? is it like db.collection("users").doc(userid).collection("activities).doc(), im not sure how to go about that

Comment: @Sinead so when a activity is created you can just push the document in sub-collection. `db.collection("users/"+userId+"/activities").add({...activityData})`. The `add()` is used to add a document with random ID which later can be used to reference while updating or deleting it. Also as mentioned if a user can have many activities then there are a high chances of hitting 1 MB max doc size limit.

Comment: That makes sense thank you! It's my first time having it that nested but when trying to query it i can do "   db.collection("userCal/"+currentUserUID+"/activities").data()" right to get the individual events?

Comment: @Sinead it's `get()` not data()... the documentation has examples of listing documents.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this meets your requirement, but from my understanding you just want to update the activities with the `allEvents` which contains all the updated activities.

```
    db.collection("userCalendar")
      .doc(currentUserUID)
      .set({
        activites: allEvents
      })
```

should become

```
    db.collection("userCalendar")
      .doc(currentUserUID)
      .set({
        activites: allEvents
      }, { merge: true })
```

Or you can use the update method

```
    db.collection("userCalendar")
      .doc(currentUserUID)
      .update({
        activites: allEvents
      })
```

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document)

> To update some fields of a document without overwriting the entire document, use the update() method:

```
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

const cityRef = doc(db, 'cities', 'BJ');
setDoc(cityRef, { capital: true }, { merge: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're overwriting your collection with every code execution:

```
db.collection("userCalendar")
          .doc(currentUserUID)
          .set({
            activites: allEvents
          })
```

You should consider to make an array union, so that the values are added to your collection instead of overwriting them:

```
db.collection("userCalendar")
          .doc(currentUserUID)
          .update({
            activites: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
                            {
                                allEvents
                            }),
          })
```

Also some examples from firestore docu:
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-data-set-array-operations

Comment: Thank you this work! How would i go about calling allEvents from firebase like this then? like getting each event object in the array?

Comment: @Sinead would be nice to upvote my answer :-)