# Swift, Firebase, array of map: why are the @DocumentIDs for each Album duplicated in each element of the Song array?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm working through Javed Davidson's "Music Player in a Day" YouTube tutorial, but with some notable changes and I'm experiencing something very unexpected; namely, I only see one song for each album.

When I walk through the code, I see that the songs have all been given the same DocumentID, which explains the symptom, but not the cause. (RHPS!)

Here's some code:

[image: Firestore data]

```
struct Album: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var title: String
    var image: String
    var releaseDate: Date
    var songs: [Song]
}

struct Song: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var title: String
    var timeInSeconds: Int
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var mpData: MusicPlayerData
    @State private var currentAlbum: Album?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(mpData.albums) { album in
                            AlbumArtView(album: album)
                                .onTapGesture { self.currentAlbum = album }
                        }
                    }
                }
                LazyVStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    if let album = currentAlbum {
                        ForEach(album.songs) { song in
                            SongCellView(album: album, song: song)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Bob Seger")
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the `ForEach(album.songs)` to `ForEach(album.songs, id:\.title)`, then it works.

But, of course, I'd prefer to use the `id` property of the struct.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Each `Song` is a struct representing elements of the `songs` array. These aren't documents, so the `@DocumentID var id: String?` will be initialised as either `nil` or `NSNull` (not a swift dev, so unsure of the specifics) because the value is missing. So pointing the iterator at `\.title` (a property that exists) is the correct approach?

Comment: Yeah, after posting, I've been thinking about it. I'm gonna try adding an `id` to the database for each element in the array.

Comment: Yup, that worked. I manually added an `id` to each Song in the array of maps in Firestore and changed the `Song` struct to just have `var id: String`. Then the original code works.

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva Can you put this an the correct answer, so other may find this?

Comment: Well, I think Peter's answer below is also correct, and perhaps a better explanation / option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look at [Jared's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LS7aJ4NISk&list=PL3MWPU0RhJzGhbQSsv1U9JcRBBlX9vF4Q&index=3) and it seems like he is not using Codable, but instead maps the documents manually, so I assume using Codable is one of the substantial changes you mention in your question.

The reason why your songs don't get a unique ID is that `@DocumentID` only works for documents.

In the screenshot we can see that you use Firestore documents for albums, and a nested array for the songs of an album. This means that the albums' document IDs will be mapped to the `id` attribute of the `Album` struct.

As a nested array is not a document, it doesn't have a document ID, so all the song ids will be `nil`, which is why you see only one song per album.

There are couple of ways around this:

1. Use the `title` as the identifying attribute (just like you did)
2. Store all the songs in a top-level collection `songs` and add an attribute `albumID` that refers to the album they belong to. This will allow you to fetch all songs belonging to an album using a query. It also allows you to assign a song to multiple albums (which might or might not be what you want).
3. Use a sub collection for the songs.

How exactly you model your data heavily depends on your use case(s), and there is no one true way of modeling this. I recommend checking out our video series about Firestore to get a deeper understanding of how to model data for Firestore: [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ), in particular [Maps, Arrays and Subcollections, Oh My! | Get to know Cloud Firestore #4 - YouTube](https://youtu.be/o7d5Zeic63s?t=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ) and [How to Structure Your Data | Get to know Cloud Firestore #5 - YouTube](https://youtu.be/haMOUb3KVSo).

To learn more about how to map your Firestore documents to/from Swift, check out this comprehensive blog post I wrote. It also contains code snippets that show how to handle mapping errors: [Mapping Firestore Data in Swift - The Comprehensive Guide](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/). There is also a fully working sample app that demonstrates all the different ways to map simple data types, custom data types, colors, arrays, dates, geopoints, etc: [peterfriese/Swift-Firestore-Guide: The Comprehensive Guide to using Cloud Firestore in Swift](https://github.com/peterfriese/Swift-Firestore-Guide).

Comment: Hi Peter. Yes, you got it, using Codable was one of the substantial changes I made. Thanks to your posts/videos/tutorials....Amazingly, the song IDs were not nil, but the same ID as the album.id....thanks for you suggestions. For the time being, I chose a fourth option: I added an id field to each map in the array.

Comment: Adding an `id` to the array elements is a viable option as well, particularly as it will prevent the items from jumping around in a `List` view if you change/edit the titles.